# unsupported Swift architecture in Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ios-frameworks, ios-library

I've been working with a static library in iOS written in Swift. Below is the script I've been using to build the library into a fat framework (universal).

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.

#1. After then, make a fresh directory directory 

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# make sure the output directory exists

mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# 2. Copy Device (arm64) Framework to a fresh universal folder location 

cp -a "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

#3. Copy Sim (x86_64) Frameworks's "MyFramework.swiftmodule" folder content and paste it in Fat (x86_64 + arm64) Frameworks's "MyFramework.swiftmodule" folder.

SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/."

if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then

cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"

fi

# Step 4: Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory

lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Step 5: Copy output to the project directory.

cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

# Step 6: Open Project Directory

open "${PROJECT_DIR}"#1. After then, make a fresh directory directory 

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# make sure the output directory exists

mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# 2. Copy Device (arm64) Framework to a fresh universal folder location 

cp -a "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

#3. Copy Sim (x86_64) Frameworks's "MyFramework.swiftmodule" folder content & paste it in Fat(x86_64 + arm64) Frameworks's  "MyFramework.swiftmodule" folder.

SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/."

if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then

cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"

fi

# Step 4: Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory

lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Step 5: Copy output to the project directory.

cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

# Step 6. Open Project Directory

open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
```

When integrated with a Swift app, the library works seamlessly for both the simulator and the device. However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to use the library in an Objective-C app on the simulator. The error message states "unsupported Swift architecture." Strangely, it works fine on the device.

If anyone could provide assistance with this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.